# Error when checking input: expected flatten_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28)

Tags: numpy, image-processing, keras, neural-network, mnist

This is the code:

```
image = cv2.imread('MNIST_IMAGE.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
data = asarray(gray)
data=data/255.0
predictions=model.predict(data)
```

And this is the error, I get:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         3 data = asarray(gray)
>         4 data=data/255.0
>   ----> 5 predictions=model.predict(data)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)    1011
>   max_queue_size=max_queue_size,    1012         workers=workers,
>   -> 1013         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)    1014     1015   def reset_metrics(self):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in predict(self, model, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
>       496         model, ModeKeys.PREDICT, x=x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose,
>       497         steps=steps, callbacks=callbacks, max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>   --> 498         workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
>       499 
>       500
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in _model_iteration(self, model, mode, x, y, batch_size, verbose,
>   sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers,
>   use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
>       424           max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>       425           workers=workers,
>   --> 426           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>       427       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(adapter)
>       428       use_sample = total_samples is not None
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in _process_inputs(model, mode, x, y, batch_size, epochs,
>   sample_weights, class_weights, shuffle, steps, distribution_strategy,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
>       644     standardize_function = None
>       645     x, y, sample_weights = standardize(
>   --> 646         x, y, sample_weight=sample_weights)
>       647   elif adapter_cls is data_adapter.ListsOfScalarsDataAdapter:
>       648     standardize_function = standardize
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
>   batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle,
>   extract_tensors_from_dataset)    2381         is_dataset=is_dataset,
>   2382         class_weight=class_weight,
>   -> 2383         batch_size=batch_size)    2384     2385   def _standardize_tensors(self, x, y, sample_weight, run_eagerly, dict_inputs,
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in _standardize_tensors(self, x, y, sample_weight, run_eagerly,
>   dict_inputs, is_dataset, class_weight, batch_size)    2408
>   feed_input_shapes,    2409           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't
>   enforce the batch size.
>   -> 2410           exception_prefix='input')    2411     2412     # Get typespecs for the input data and sanitize it if necessary.
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py
>   in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis,
>   exception_prefix)
>       571                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
>       572                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
>   --> 573                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
>       574         if not check_batch_axis:
>       575           data_shape = data_shape[1:]
>
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_1_input to
>   have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add batch dimension:

```py
predictions = model.predict(data[None, ...])
```

Or like this (both are equivalent):

```py
predictions = model.predict(np.expand_dims(data, 0))
```

Comment: Also batch dimension, since it is a single image.

prediction = model.predict(np.array([np.expand_dims(data, -1)]))

Comment: @PratikRanjan Try: `predictions = model.predict(data[None, ..., None])`